# How to compare two Streams in IBM RTC?

Tags: java, eclipse, rtc

We have many streams in my project such as Development stream which is undergone for development (Addition of extra codes compare to prod stream), Prod/Realease stream which is already their in prod and also few others streams are their.

My Question is: How can I compare one stream with other stream to check the extra classes and files is being used?

The Issue is: while comparing one stream to other, it show all the check-ins happened with respect to each stream.

Is there a way to show, when I can compare all the files one stream to other stream , only the difference and extra files in each  stream?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [`lscm diff` command](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_4.0.1/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/diff.html).
It works [for file comparison](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/107966/file-comparison-to-display-lines-changed-on-2-streams-using-rtc-cli), but can also compare streams (see "[diff example](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fdiff_ex.html)").

If (when using streams), it lists only changesets, then you would need to script (a [bit as in this example](https://jazz.net/library/article/1031)) in order to diff changesets and then files.